# py2exe not working - flashing console and closes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, py2exe

EXE won't open. I have tried everything I found online.
When I run the exe the console opens for a few seconds and then closes.
How can I make this `.py` executable and have my `.txt` output?

```
from tkinter import *
import time, os, fnmatch, shutil

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("600x450")
screen.configure(background='azure')
screen.title("M")
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%b-%d-%Y_%H%M', t)
BACKUP_NAME = ("backup-" + timestamp)
heading = Label(text = "Mr", font=(None, 15), bg = "lightblue", fg = "black", width = "500", height = "3")
heading.pack()
firstname_text = Label(text = "Name/ * ", bg = "azure",)
lastname_text = Label(text = "Usagel* ", bg = "azure",)
material_text = Label(text = "M * ", bg = "azure",)
age_text = Label(text = "How * ", bg = "azure",)
firstname_text.place(x = 15, y = 80)
lastname_text.place(x = 15, y = 140)
material_text.place(x = 15, y = 210)
age_text.place(x = 15, y = 260)
firstname = StringVar()
lastname = StringVar()
material = StringVar()
age = StringVar()
firstname_entry = Entry(textvariable = firstname, width = "30")
lastname_entry = Entry(textvariable = lastname, width = "30")
material_entry = Entry(textvariable = material, width = "30")
age_entry = Entry(textvariable = age, width = "30")
firstname_entry.place(x = 15, y = 100)
lastname_entry.place(x = 15, y = 170)
material_entry.place(x = 15, y = 240)
age_entry.place(x = 15, y = 290)
register = Button(screen,text = "Submit", font=(None, 10), width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "lime green")
register.place(x = 15, y = 320)
```

Comment: What is the command that you are running from the cmd?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have nothing to keep the window open. Something like a `mainloop()`... see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program)